# Case sensitive match on OS-X

Tags: macos, nginx

I have a URL redirect in nginx as follows:

```
location = /MyWorkouts {
    rewrite ^ /myworkouts permanent;
}
```

All of our linux test and production boxes work fine with this. However, on our dev boxes, nginx appears to be matching both "/MyWorkouts" and "/myworkouts" with this rule.

My guess is that nginx is storing a cache file somewhere with the URL path as part of the name, and the OS-X filesystem is case-insensitive.

Is this the issue? Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure it's a cache?  You could test this hypothesis by creating another path with a similar redirect before visiting it.

Comment: @Ssswift No, I'm not. but I'm thinking that any URL would behave pretty much the same way.

Comment: "Location matching in the case-insensitive operating systems always performs in a case-insensitive way." -- https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/87

Comment: I would accept that answer if you posted it as one. Thanks!

Comment: If you start *"Disk Utility"* (from *Applications/Utilities*) you can select the filesystem you are using and click **Info** and see if it is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to one of the Nginx developers:

> "Location matching in the case-insensitive operating systems always
>   performs in a case-insensitive way."

Source: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/87

You may be able to force the behavior you want with regex matching.